# Expo and React Native: Ready for production

Tags: react-native, expo, detach, create-react-app

1) When I starting to move the application for production or for public testing. I just call the 'exp detach' to generate the iOS and android file and follow the same process as normal native application.

2) Can it be publish without detaching the application?

3) Once detach, can it be attached back to expo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You don't need to do this, you can run `exp build:ios` or `exp build:android` https://docs.expo.io/versions/v27.0.0/distribution/building-standalone-apps

2) Yup: https://docs.expo.io/versions/v27.0.0/distribution/app-stores

3) Yes, to see what the difference is I'd suggest detaching and then deleting the `ios` and `android` directories and then running `git diff`